# Why close this as too localized?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[Can I perform a code review although I am very inexperienced?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/201814/can-i-perform-a-code-review-although-i-am-very-inexperienced)

I see people closing this as too localized. Can someone explain why? To me it looks on topic and ok.

Comment: This is a bit premature, the question isn't closed (yet?).

Comment: @YannisRizos Now it is ;) (if you like, feel free to delete this question. I tried, but couldn't)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the question applies only to this particular person, given his specific circumstances and experience level.

Comment: Ok, I may have misunderstood the question. Seeing it is closed, and re-reading it again, I do see it as too localized.